# Solution for type assertion without generics with Golang?

Tags: go, type-assertion

I'm using gorm, and it allows many data types like `int, uint, int8, uint8 ....`

Then I have a plugin in template like this:

```
f["UNIX2STR"] = func(t interface{}, f string) string {
        switch t.(type) {
        case int:
            return time.Unix(int64(t.(int)), 0).Format(f)
        case uint:
            return time.Unix(int64(t.(uint)), 0).Format(f)
        case uint8:
            return time.Unix(int64(t.(uint8)), 0).Format(f)
        case *int:
            return time.Unix(int64(*t.(*int)), 0).Format(f)
        case *uint:
            return time.Unix(int64(*t.(*uint)), 0).Format(f)
        case *uint8:
            return time.Unix(int64(*t.(*uint8)), 0).Format(f)
        .....
        default:
            return ""
        }
        // return time.Unix(int64(t), 0).Format(f)
    }
```

It converts all integer types to formatted string.
So what am I suppose to do? List all gorm supported int types and cast it to `int64`?

I have searched many days for solution convert `interface{}` to its true type without using type assertion but didn't work.

Comment: What are you supposed to do for what? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Flimzy i don't want to list all integer types, and do it with one single line. like `return time.Unix(int64(t.(trueType)), 0).Format(f)`. You didn't see the trouble here? With a single function i have to switch/case atleast 8 times to do a simple task

Comment: @Flimzy `I have searched many days for solution convert interface{} to its true type without using type assertion but didn't work.` Didn't read this line?

Comment: I don't see the trouble, because I don't see what you're trying to accomplish. You're focusing on a specific solution, but haven't explained the problem yet.  What is the reason you need that switch statement? What is the _goal_ you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I've been using Go for database access with gorm and similar libraries for years, and never felt the need for a large switch statement like you have in your question. There's almost certainly a different way to approach your problem, but without knowing your goal, it's hard to say.  In other words, this looks like an XY problem.

Comment: @Flimzy I simply want to avoid having error while convert all integer types to string without using switch/case. If you can provide other approach, please do it. I switched from other language to Go, and lacking of generics cause many trouble with me. This is the example.

Comment: It looks to me like he may be writing the row results to a map rather than directly into a struct, and then doing the conversion himself later on. I've done this before and started getting types like `[]uint8` instead of the ones I expected

Comment: Your goal is to provide a formatting function that converts unix timestamps to formatted date strings. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used gorm, but I think that something like this could solve your problem:

```
func formatUnix(t interface{}, f string) (string, error) {
    timestampStr := fmt.Sprint(t)
    timestamp, err := strconv.ParseInt(timestampStr, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return time.Unix(timestamp, 0).Format(f), nil
}
```

Rather than listing all potential types, it simply converts the `interface{}` to a `string` using `fmt.Sprint()` and then convert the `string` to `int64` using `strconv.ParseInt()`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you're concerned with converting any numeric type to a string. This is easily done with [`fmt.Sprint`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprint):

```
stringValue := fmt.Sprint(i) // i is any type
```

But this has nothing to do with GORM.

On the other hand, if your problem is that GORM is returning an unpredictable type, just change your select statement to always return a string.  For example, for MySQL, something like:

```
SELECT CAST(someNumberColumn AS VARCHAR) AS stringColumn
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(someNumberColumn AS INT) AS intColumn
```

Comment: Gorm supports both pointer type and normal type, datetime field can be `int` or `*int`, so it means if the filed type is a pointer, template function can't convert it to string

Comment: I don't know what template functions you're talking about, but since this question doesn't deal with templates, a separate question is probably in order.

Comment: It's a part of the question. You see i mentioned the pointer type in the question `*int`, and `Sprint(*i)` doesn't work with pointer type

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this is a problem with go or gorm. I am a bit baffled that you save your unix timestamps in many different formats. BTW, A unix timestamp is 32 bit, so there is no point in converting (and saving in the first place) any 8 bit ints.

A solution would be to use a unified data type (int64) for all timestamps in your structs. After that your formatting func can accept `int64` instead of`interface{}`, without the need of any type assertions.

Comment: I didn't say this is the problem with gorm. It's golang problem, it doesn't support generics. This is why we have to use switch/case to type assert all types. Using `int64` causes the memory. Why i have to use `int64` with field has only 0,1,2 numbers. And this is for design pattern, we can't force other developers to use only `int64` in datetime field while `gorm` support every integer types it means anyone can use any type for any field they wanted, so the logic code have to handle all of it.

Comment: I did not suggest to use int64 for all number fields. Just use it for the timestamps. You can use int32 if you are concerned about memory, but it should be at least 32 bit for unix timestamps. Printing out any other number as a formatted date string does not really make sense, or am I missing something? 

Because something is possible, does not mean that you should use it. Why would you use an arbitrary number of data types for the same type of data? It is a sensible convention to specify that all timestamps are saved in 32 bit. Then your func could accept `int32` instead of `interface{}`.

Comment: There are millions of code logic. Like the example above: convert unixtimestamp (integer data fields) to formatted string. Since then gorm supports all type of integers. What will you do to solve this trouble? Like i sasid, sensible convention or common sense is based on perspective of each developer, not everyone have the same coding style and for doing good, we have to trap all the cases in code logic. Using `Sprint` actually a nice trick, but not a proper way to solve the trouble like having generics

Comment: Sorry, I was only trying to help. I tried to answer your question to my knowledge and my understanding.